# ProgrammingError: relation "mail_thread" does not exist

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

When i trying to send reply for a mail i getting  this error:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "mail_thread" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "mail_thread" SET "message_last_post"='2017-02-13 12:...
```

I have installed `mail` module, but the model `mail.thred` doesn't create. 
How can i resolve this?.

Comment: Could you add the code, where you send the reply? The Odoo model `email.thread` is an abstract model, so there will be no table in database for it.

Comment: Similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456608/error-when-sending-email-through-code-in-odoo/45442439#45442439)